# multirow with paragraph

Tags: tables, lyx, paragraphs, multirow

I created a multirow table in LyX. When I tried to convert it to PDF, LyX hang and I had to kill the process.

Finally, I narrowed the problem down to a MWE where there is only a single multirow cell, containing a paragraph. Here is the LyX file:

```
#LyX 2.0 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 413
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100

\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_amsmath 1
\use_esint 1
\use_mhchem 1
\use_mathdots 1
\cite_engine basic
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Tabular
<lyxtabular version="3" rows="2" columns="1">
<features tabularvalignment="middle">
<column alignment="left" valignment="top" width="2.5cm">
<row>
<cell multirow="3" alignment="left" valignment="middle" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\size tiny
C
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\size tiny
D
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell multirow="4" alignment="left" valignment="middle" topline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
</lyxtabular>

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Here it is exported to LaTeX:

```
%% LyX 2.0.5.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright}p{2.5cm}|}
\hline 
\multirow{2}{2.5cm}{{\tiny C}{\tiny \par}

{\tiny D}}\tabularnewline
\tabularnewline
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

When I run pdflatex on this LaTeX file, I get the following output:

```
erelsgl@erelsgl-H61MLC:~/Dropbox/papers/FairAndSquare$ pdflatex multirow2.tex This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./multirow2.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2012-05-30, ngerman-x-2012-05-30, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, friulan, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, h
ungarian, icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, ma
rathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, 
kurmanji, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk,
 polish, portuguese, romanian, romansh, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbianc, s
lovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, 
welsh, loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latin9.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/english.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def)))
(./multirow2.aux)
Runaway argument?
{{\tiny C}{\tiny 
! Paragraph ended before \@xmultirow was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.21 A & \multirow{2}{2.5cm}{{\tiny C}{\tiny \par
                                                 }
?
```

I am not sure where exactly the problem lies:

- Is it a problem of LyX, that generates wrong LaTeX output?
- Is it a problem of pdflatex, that doesn't know how to read that LaTeX output?

What should I do to have this multirow table correctly converted to pdf?

Comment: The `\par` is the problem. The row is not a `parbox` hence it cannot break lines into paragraphs.

Comment: I didn't create the TeX... it was created automatically by LyX export. do you say there is a bug in LyX?

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi if this is a `LyX` bug, can you please report this at http://www.lyx.org/trac ?

Comment: I tried, but I can't register to Trac (the verification email never arrives)

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi I'm guessing you checked the spam email. That's strange. Well thanks for trying. Also, if you leave a comment for someone they're only notified if you address it to them (with @). I just happened to check back so I saw it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider the following LaTeX MWE:

[image]

```
%% LyX 2.0.5.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright}p{2.5cm}|}
\hline 
\multirow{2}{*}{%
    \parbox{2.5cm}{%
        {\tiny C}\\%
        {\tiny D}%
        }%
    }
\tabularnewline
\tabularnewline
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do I do this in LyX? I tried adding a ParBox inside the multirow cell, and putting the paragraph inside, but it didn't help.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi Let me give it a try and will get back to you in little while.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi Seems Lyx does create the error. I cannot help further if you do not tell me exactly what you will be doing with the C and D. You can insert a `parbox` by going to `insert > box > frameless`. After this right click on what says `minipage` and select `settings` There you can change into `parbox`.

Comment: I did just this, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Finally I solved the problem by replacing the paragraphs with line-breaks, which achieve the same effect.